# Visual Basic 2010 Express - How do you switch back and forth between two images that are on top of each other?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, express, basic

I really need some help with this dilemma.

I have two pictures of a light bulb. In one picture the light bulb is shining brightly and in the other it’s turned off. I’m supposed to overlap these pics and make it turn on and off by clicking on the image but I just can’t figure out the code for it. How do you toggle between these images? I am not allowed to use a button to do this. I've got to click on the pic to change it. Please help! Link below as I do not have enough rep to post actual images yet.

http://i1293.photobucket.com/albums/b598/BentoBoy1/ScreenHunter_02Sep202252_zps75800aea.png

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub ExitButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitButton.Click
        'Close the program
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

```
Private Sub PrintButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PrintButton.Click
    'Print the form in the print preview window
    PrintForm1.PrintAction = Printing.PrintAction.PrintToPreview
    PrintForm1.Print()

End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    'Turn the light bulb on.
    MessageLabel.Text = "Turn on the light"
End Sub

Private Sub Label2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MessageLabel.Click
    'Display different messages when the light bulbs are clicked.
End Sub

Private Sub RedRadioButton_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RedRadioButton.CheckedChanged
    'Set the MessageLabel text to Red.
    MessageLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red
End Sub

Private Sub BlackRadioButton_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BlackRadioButton.CheckedChanged
    'Set the MessageLabel text to Black.
    MessageLabel.ForeColor = Color.Black
End Sub

Private Sub BlueRadioButton_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BlueRadioButton.CheckedChanged
    'Set the MessageLabel text to Blue.
    MessageLabel.ForeColor = Color.Blue
End Sub

Private Sub GreenRadioButton_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GreenRadioButton.CheckedChanged
    'Set the MessageLabel text to Green.
    MessageLabel.ForeColor = Color.Green
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ProgrammedByLabel.Click
    'Programmed by me.
End Sub

Private Sub ColorsGroupBox_Enter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ColorsGroupBox.Enter
    'Group of different colors.
End Sub

Private Sub NameTextBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NameTextBox.TextChanged
    'Name field.
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LightOnPictureBox.Click
    'Light bulb is on.
    LightOnPictureBox.Image = My.Resources.lighton
    MessageLabel.Text = "Thanks for turning me on, " & NameTextBox.Text
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LightOffPictureBox.Click
    'Light bulb is off.
    LightOffPictureBox.Image = My.Resources.lightoff
    MessageLabel.Text = "Thanks for turning me off, " & NameTextBox.Text
End Sub

Private Sub NameLabel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NameLabel.Click
    'Name label.
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, i think that you should take a look [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/303904-using-an-if-statement-to-check-image-in-picture-box/) in order to understand the way images comparisson takes place. Secondly, the proper event to change the picture is the PictureBox.Click...
The code should be like the following one:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim imageBulbOff As Image = My.Resources.BulbOff
    Dim imageBulbOn As Image = My.Resources.BulbOn
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        PictureBox1.Image = imageBulbOff
    End Sub
    Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
        If PictureBox1.Image Is imageBulbOff Then
            PictureBox1.Image = imageBulbOn
        Else
            PictureBox1.Image = imageBulbOff
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```